# Radio button selection is slow if apply conditions on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio button. When I click on it more than 50 fields are disabled, some texts are changed and few classes are added using jquery. Everything works fine except the radio button selection shows a delay in getting selected.
I know that DOM manipulation slows down the UI rendering. Is there any possible solution for this problem?

Unfortunately I can't show the exact code, but I can provide some sample for better understanding -

```
$(document).ready(callMe);
function callMe() {
    $("#text-field").on("change", function(){
        var value = $("#text-field").val();
        $("#value").html("yo" + value);
    }).trigger("change");
}



<input type="text" id="text-field">
<p id="value"></p>
```

Please Note - This is just a sample manipulation, In actual code there are plenty of manipulations required which takes time and hence slows down the rendering of selection of radio button.

Comment: We need to see your code, and a little more information. No frameworks or other libraries are being used, just jQuery?

Comment: Can you paste the code. Maybe there is some optimization we can help you with?

Are you querying the same element everytime you click, maybe there is a better selector or something?

Comment: Hi, I can't provide the exact code. I've updated the question with the sample of what I'm doing in actual code.

Comment: Why are you triggering "change" ?

Comment: I need to call the function on `onload` and on `oncange` event.

Comment: You don't need to"trigger" a change event on the chained jQuery object. But it should have been only happening once, so it's not that big of a deal, just entirely unnecessary

Comment: Let me give it a try.

Comment: Honestly I think your problem is something else, there's nothing wrong with your initial sample other than it has an event trigger that isn't needed, and you select the element every change even, but shouldn't be too big of a deal in this context.

Comment: Actually on single click I've to do a lot of manipulations as I stated in question like adding classes to elements and their parent nodes, disabling them, altering some texts, adding some css.

Comment: I tried to cache jQuery objects too to reduce the DOM searching time for elements by assigning references to a variable and then using it to alter the DOM. Something like this - `var x =  $(.some-class);` `x.addClass('disabled');`

Answer (score 0):

Okay Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const $val = $("#value");
    const $textField = $("#textField");
    textField.on("change", function ( val ){
        $val.html("yo" + this.value);
    });
    $val.html("yo" + $textField.val() );
}); 



<input type="text" id="textField">
<p id="value"></p>
```

Comment: After removing `trigger()` it doesn't load on `onload`

Comment: Then just put 'yo' in the <p> tag :D

Comment: Why not, it's essentially what's happening? `this.value` will be ''... same thing.

Comment: Relic this is a sample, it doesn't have to do anything with real scenario. In actual implementation, I'm adding classes, adding attributes and so on not just changing the text of a paragraph. :D

Comment: I can't help more if I don't have more to go on... can you extend you sample to reflect what's actually going on then? Either way you shouldn't trigger the event, I'll edit my answer to include onload additions

Comment: I can but for that I need some time. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155112/discussion-between-relic-and-rudraksh-pathak).

Comment: Sure. Good idea.